# How do I insert a restart game option?

Tags: python, loops

I would like to have an option at the end of my dice game which says:

> Do you want to restart? Yes or No

If the user types yes, the game restarts and this an infinite number of times, until the user has had enough of the game and quits.

I know you can do this with a loop, but how?

```
import random

print("Dice Game: try to roll a bigger number than the computer! Good luck!")

print("Type 'go' to roll")
dieroll = input()
if dieroll == 'go':
    myNumber = random.randint(1,6)
    pcNumber = random.randint(1,6)
    print("You rolled " + str(myNumber))
    print("He rolled " + str(pcNumber))
    if myNumber < pcNumber:
        print("You lose!")
    if pcNumber < myNumber:
        print("You win!")
```

Comment: please take a look at this tutorial and learn about loops.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your game into the function for example `game()` and the execute it in infinite while loop. If the user says NO it exits the loop, otherwise it runs again. And so on...

```py
    while True:
        game()
        restart = input('do you want to restart Y/N?')
        if restart == 'N'
            break
        elif restart == 'Y':
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to implement this option.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
import random

# Instructions for starting the game

while True:
    print("Type 'go' to roll")
    dieroll = input()
    if dieroll == 'go':
        myNumber, pcNumber = random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6)
        print("You rolled " + str(myNumber))
        print("He rolled " + str(pcNumber))
        if myNumber <= pcNumber:
            print("You lose!")
        else:
            print("You win!")

    print("Do you want to restart ? Yes or No")
    response = input()
    if not response == "Yes":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should pack your code into a function for example

```
def game():
    your code
```

For user prompt you can use raw_input() - Python 2.x and input() in Python 3.x
At the end of your program try add something like this:

```
answer = raw_input("Restart?")
if answer == "Yes":
    print "Leaving the game"
    sys.exit(0) # import sys module 
elif answer == "No":
    print "Starting new game"
    game()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to divide your program up into separate functions for each task. It will become easy to read and modify, so a restart function can easily be created and implemented.

The function restart() returns a bool depending on the users input. The main startGame loop checks for this value each iteration of the while loop.

When the user wants to stop playing (False) the function returns and the program stops.

```
import random

def rollDie():
    myNumber = random.randint(1, 6)
    pcNumber = random.randint(1, 6)

    print("You rolled %d" % myNumber)
    print("The PC rolled %d" % pcNumber)

    if myNumber > pcNumber:
        return "--- You win! ---"
    else:
        return "--- You lose! ---"

def restart():
    user_input = input("Would you like to play again? Type 'Yes' or 'No'\n\n")

    if user_input.lower() == "no": # Converts input to lowercase for comparison
        return False
    elif user_input.lower() == "yes":
        return True

def startGame():
    while True:
        user_input = input("Dice Game: Try to roll a bigger number than the computer! Good Luck \n" +
                          "Type 'go' to roll the die... \n\n")

        if user_input == "go":
             print(rollDie())
            if not restart():
                return

startGame()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the functionality of restarting the game in OOP python, just put the entire main.py code inside a function and trigger the function at the end of main.py. Inside main.py file after writing the question statement, in  (If part) first clear the screen then trigger the function in which you put the code of main.py file, and in (else part) make boolean statement false.

```
**def game():**
import time
from turtle import Screen
from player import Player
from car_manager import CarManager
from scoreboard import Scoreboard

SPEED = 0.1
player = Player()
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

car_manager = CarManager()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(player.move, "Up")
scoreboard = Scoreboard()

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(SPEED)
    screen.update()

    car_manager.create_car()
    car_manager.move()

    for car in car_manager.all_cars:
        if car.distance(player) < 20:
            game_is_on = False
            scoreboard.game_over()
            **q = screen.textinput("Restart", "Do you want to restart? ")
            if q == "yes".lower():
                screen.clear()
                game()
            else:
                game_is_on = False**

    if player.is_at_finish():
        player.start()
        car_manager.level_up()
        car_manager.box_inc()
        scoreboard.score_up()
screen.exitonclick()
```

**game()**

Answer (score -1):

I just submitted a post on a similar issue. Let me know if this helps:

[Simple Python Game Restart Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476582/8142237)

To fit your specific needs, you could update the restart code to read as follows to allow for a Yes/No input option.

```
play_again = input("Do you want to restart? Yes or No\n")

if play_again == "Yes":
    exec(open("./yourfilenamehere.py").read())
else:
    exit()
```

Comment: That's a very poor solution.

Comment: What's wrong with running this to restart a simple game? I just started coding, so any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Proper solution using `while` loop has been already given in one of the answers to this question.